# How to hide default lang in url asp core

Tags: asp.net-core

I use 3 language in my app. Guies from SEO said that I mast hide default language from URL. How can I do it with using mapping routes in asp core 3.1?

My code:

```
        app.UseRouter(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapMiddlewareRoute("{culture=ru}/{*mvcRoute}", subApp =>
            {
                subApp.UseRequestLocalization(localizationOptions);

                subApp.UseMvc(mvcRoutes =>
                {                       
                    mvcRoutes.MapRoute(
                        name: "default",
                        template: "{culture=ru}/{action}/{id?}",
                        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
                     );
                });
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default1",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
               name: "default1",
               pattern: "{culture=ru}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
               defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
```